# Javafx dynamically fxml load at Runtime

Tags: dynamic, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have an application that cover a wide number of use cases each with completely independent workflows but workflows are pretty static after installation.

I have therefore created an HBox placeholder that will load the workflow for an installation.

Is there a way to dynamically load a section of the fxml from a database or a separate file archive? This fpml will have to have its own set of images and resources needed to achieve the workflows functionality.

TBH, I don't know where to start on this one.

Regards

Comment: What do you actually mean by "dynamically" here? An FXML file is only ever loaded at runtime. Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your problem. You can modify the scene graph at any time you want. So, of course it is possible to load a part of the scene graph from an FXML file at any time and hook it up to the already existing part. In your controller you have access to your HBox placeholder and when you have loaded the second part of the scene graph you can just add it via hbox.getChildren().add(newpart), were newpart is the root node of your second scene graph part. Of course you have to make sure that the layout works correctly for your constellation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems nonsense because the FXML is always loaded dynamically. My guess is you are confused because most of the examples use FXML in the same bundle as the classes and so are loaded trough the getResource method. But the FXML loader takes any kind of InputStream, so you can just open a database blob or a file as an InputStream and give that InputStream as an argument to the loader. Be sure to catch the runtime exceptions though :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I have images that go with that FXML loaded from the db, how should I reference it in the FXML?